# Numpy polyfit and numpy polynomial

Tags: python, numpy, regression, polynomials

Hey so far I was using `numpy.polyfit` to fit the data but I see that there is available new class `numpy.polynomial` where I can choose for example Chebyshev series. From documentation I know that I can take
`from numpy.polynomial import Chebyshev c = Chebyshev.fit(xdata, ydata, deg=1)`

But what is the equivalent function to `numpy.polyval` in this class?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that may help you out figure out the modified `polyval` of `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> t = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(3,[1,1,1]) # f(3) = 1 + 1*x**1 + 1*x**2

>>> print(t)

13.0
```

You can find more about the modified version in this link: [np.polynomial.polynomial](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html).